# заполнение массива по спирали в Си

Tags: c

Помогите написать алгоритм, где вводится значение n и он создает 2-х мерный массив n*n, который заполняется спиралью от 1 до n^2

Comment: каким образом вам помочь?

Comment: алгоритм ведь вы уже сами написали прямо в тексте вопроса.

Comment: я имел ввиду программный код, а не алгоритм, просто все мои попытки не работали адекватно

Comment: Вопрос неправильно сформулирован, должно быть что-то вроде: "двое из ларца, напишите вместо меня решение задачки, а то мне думать лень"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм предельно прост

1. Считываем размер массива
2. Аллоцируем память
3. Начинаем двигать текущие индексы в зависимости от текущего начала и границцы заполнения
4. Выводим массив
5. Прибераем за собой

Пример:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int N, M;

    scanf("%d%d", &N, &M);
    int **a = (int **)malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = (int *)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
    }

    int iStart = 0, iBord = 0, jStart = 0, jBord = 0;

    int k = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (k <= N * M)
    {
        a[i][j] = k;
        if (i == iStart && j < M - jBord - 1)
            ++j;
        else if (j == M - jBord - 1 && i < N - iBord - 1)
            ++i;
        else if (i == N - iBord - 1 && j > jStart)
            --j;
        else
            --i;

        if ((i == iStart + 1) && (j == jStart) && (jStart != M - jBord - 1))
        {
            ++iStart;
            ++iBord;
            ++jStart;
            ++jBord;
        }
        ++k;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i])
        {
            free((int *)a[i]);
        }
    }
    if (a)
    {
        free(a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```